# Z-index on two divs where both are active

Tags: html, css

Hello I would like to know how I can make 2 div's one hovering another in this case the left is hovering the right one but the elements like button's etc to be active on the both div's the left one to have priority. Bellow is my code where the left div is overtaking the right div.

I have 2 problems. the right div 1. all his buttons are becoming inactive on the right div. I want them to be active and the height of it to be complete because now since it is on the back the footer is overlapping it.And at the same time the left div to be over the right one but only it's area to be active like buttons and etc.

```
<div class="left"></div>
<div class="right overlap"></div>
<footer>footer</footer>
```

**CSS:**

```
.overlap {z-index: -1; position: absolute;};
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? Can you display a sample possibly? I believe I know how to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if i understand correctly you are looking for something like this:

[https://jsfiddle.net/9mwb8gx2/][1]

```
[1]: https://jsfiddle.net/9mwb8gx2/
```

Answer (score 0):

If i understand correctly, you want the right div to partially overlap the left div. but you are trying to put the z-index for the entire div. you just need to put multiple div inside the left or right div and then put the z-index accordingly.

If you are trying to achieve pop-up with z-index, i recommend you put more code in your question so that we get what you are trying to do, a fiddle will also be helpful.